# Describing convergence with probability $1$ in "finite" terms, proof correct

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I tried to solve the following exercise:

> Show that $Z_n \to Z$ with probability $1$ if and only if for every $\varepsilon$ there exists some $n$ such that $P(|Z_k - Z| < \varepsilon, n \le k \le m) > 1 - \varepsilon$ for all $m$ exceeding $n$.

It would be nice if you could tell if my proof is correct, and maybe if there exists some simpler one. First, by considering the complement of $\{ \lim_k Z_k = Z \}$ we see that
$$
 P(\{ \lim Z_k = Z \}) = 1 \quad\mbox{ iff }\quad P(|Z_k - Z| \ge \varepsilon \mbox{ i.o} ) = 0
$$
for each $\varepsilon > 0$, I use this characterisation of convergence with probability $1$. Also note that 
$$
 P(|Z_k - Z| < \varepsilon, n \le k \le m) > 1 - \varepsilon \quad\mbox{ iff }\quad
 P\left(\bigcup_{k=n}^m \{ |Z_k - Z| \ge \varepsilon \right) < \varepsilon
$$
by considering the complement.

**Proof**: i) Suppose there exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for each $n$ there exists some $m > n$ so that
$$
 P\left( \bigcup_{n=k}^m |Z_k - Z| \ge \varepsilon \right) \ge \varepsilon.
$$
Set $A_k := \{ |Z_k - Z| \ge \varepsilon \}$, we have 
$\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k \supseteq \bigcup_{k=n}^m A_k$ for all $n$, therefore
$$
 P\left( \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k \right) \ge \varepsilon.
$$
Further $\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k \downarrow \limsup A_k$ and therefore
$$
 P\left( \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k \right) \downarrow P(\limsup A_k)
$$
which implies $P(\limsup A_k) \ge \varepsilon > 0$, and as
$\limsup A_k = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k = \{ |Z_k - Z| \ge \varepsilon \mbox{ i.o.} \}$, there could not be convergence with probability $1$.

ii) Suppose for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists some $n$ such that
$$
 P\left( \bigcup_{k=n}^{m} \{ |Z_k - Z| \ge \varepsilon \} \right) \le \varepsilon
$$
for all $m > n$. Fix some $\varepsilon > 0$ and again set $A_k := \{ |Z_k - Z| \ge \varepsilon \}$, and as
$\bigcup_{k=n}^m A_k \uparrow \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k$ for $m \to \infty$ implies $P(\bigcup_{k=n}^m A_k) \uparrow P(\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k)$ for $m \to \infty$ we have
$$
 P\left( \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k \right) \le \varepsilon.
$$
Further $\limsup A_k \subseteq \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k$ for each $n$. Now suppose some $\varepsilon > 0$ is given and let $0 < \delta < \varepsilon$ be arbitrary, then there exists for $\delta$ some $n$ such that
$$
 P\left( \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} \{ |Z_k - Z| \ge \delta\} \right) \le \delta.
$$
As $\{ |Z_k - Z| \ge \varepsilon \} \subseteq \{|Z_k - Z| \ge \delta\}$ we have
$$
 \{ |Z_k - Z| \ge \varepsilon \mbox{ i.o} \}
 \subseteq \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}\{ |Z_k - Z| \ge \varepsilon \}
 \subseteq \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}\{ |Z_k - Z| \ge \delta \}
$$
and therefore
$$
 P(\{ |Z_k - Z| \ge \varepsilon \mbox{ i.o} \} \le \delta
$$
for all $0 < \delta < \varepsilon$, which implies $P(\{ |Z_k - Z| \ge \varepsilon \mbox{ i.o} \} = 0$, which shows convergence with probability $1$. $\square$

Comment: Your first statement is not correct. $\mathbb{P}(|Z_k-Z| \geq \epsilon)$ does not necessary hold if $\mathbb{P}(\lim Z_k = Z)=1$. (Just in case you forgot the "lim" at the right-hand side: it is still not correct. $\lim_k \mathbb{P}(|Z_k-Z| \geq \epsilon)=0$ does not imply $\mathbb{P}(\lim Z_k = Z)=1$.)

Comment: Yes, this was a typo, sorry, I meant $P(|Z_k - Z| \ge \varepsilon \mbox{ infinitely often}) = 0$ for all $\varepsilon$, i.e. $\limsup \{ |Z_k - Z| \ge \varepsilon \} = \{ |Z_k - Z|\ge \varepsilon \mbox{ i.o} \}$. This follows by considering $\{ \lim Z_k = Z \}^C = \bigcup_{\varepsilon} \{ |Z_k - Z| \ge \varepsilon \mbox{ i.o} \}$, as $\lim Z_k(\omega) \ne Z(\omega)$ iff there exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $|Z_k(\omega) - Z(\omega)| \ge \varepsilon$ for infinitely many $k$.

Comment: Okay; the remaining part of your proof is fine.